# Ajax not capturing php contact form script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a contact form on my website that is not posting the success or error message as it should.

The weird thing is I have used this exact same form, php, and ajax script on several other sites and it works great. In fact, it used to work great on the site in question.

The website is https://www.pouncingfoxdesign.com. The contact form is at the bottom. Feel free to fill it out for testing purposes.

Here's the form and script:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 wow form1 fadeInLeft">
            <div class="contact-form clearfix contactForm">
                <form id="form" action="php/email.php" class="contactForm" 
method="post">
                <div class="messages"></div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  
placeholder="Your Name" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field message">
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Your Message" required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-blue 
pull-right" value="SEND MESSAGE" id="msg-submit">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha fadeInLeft" data-
sitekey=""></div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- end .contact-form -->
        </div> <!-- .col-md-8 -->


<script> $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevents default submit
    var form = $(this); 
    var post_url = form.attr('action'); 
    var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for   
process.php
    // $('#loader', '#form').html('<img src="img/forms/loading.gif" /> 
Please Wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/email.php', // Your form script
        data: post_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            var old_html = form.html()
            $(form)
                .html(msg).fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(form)
                    .html(old_html).fadeIn();
            }, 4000); 
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, err){
            var old_html = form.html()
            $(form).fadeOut(500)
                .html("<h3>There was an error. Please try again.
</h3>").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(form).fadeOut(500)
                    .html(old_html).fadeIn();
            }, 3000); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$success = "
<div class=\"row-fluid\">
<div class=\"span12\">
    <h1>Submission successful</h1>
    <h3>Thank you for contacting us!</h3>
</div>
</div>";


$to = "email@email.com";
$subject = "$name\n filled Pouncing Fox Desing Form";
$txt = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Comments:\n $message";
$headers = "From: Pouncing Fox Design" . "\r\n" ;

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $secretKey = "";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$response=file_get_contents
("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?  
secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

if (mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers)) {
    echo "$success"
} else {
echo 'Form submission failed. Please try again...'; // failure
}
?>
```

What I want it to do is replace the form with the success message for a few seconds and then go back to the form. What it does instead is just go to the email.php file with the success message being all that's on the screen.

If you want to check out https://www.mooreengaging.com, the same script and php file is used for that site. It works great and you can see my intended results. Again, feel free to fill out the form for testing purposes.

I have tried to use other ajax scripts and have tried to rework it several different times, but no matter what when clicking submit it just loads the php file. It's like it is bypassing the ajax script altogether.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have received the emails from you guys testing and they look right. So it is working, just not posting the success message as I'd like.

Comment: `echo "$success"` is missing a `;` and remove the quotes from this `"$success"`.

Comment: Also, not sure if it's actually in your script, but `process.php` and `Please Wait...');` are going to cause some trouble.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` should be `e.preventDefault()`, because you named the event parameter `e`.

Comment: your form has an action on it remove that and use the event handler only. like Barmar stated which is why the default action is still happening.

Comment: @pmahomme I tried modifying 'echo "$success"' to no avail. I guess I am wondering why the code needs to change since the exact same code works elsewhere. I feel like there is an issue with ajax not responding. Would it help for me to post what javascript I am referencing?

Comment: @Barmar I changed "event" to "e". No dice.

Comment: @NickTaylor Didn't you see the comment above about the syntax error in the PHP?

Comment: @Barmar sorry yes, I added `;` to `success` and changed the `event` to `e`

Comment: It looks like the Javascript to bind the submit handler isn't being executed. Maybe it's because it has `type="text/rocketscript"` instead of `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: @Barmar Where is that? I am not seeing that in my index.html.

Comment: Now I can't find it. But when I go to your site, I don't see the contact form any more, either.

Comment: But the script line looks something like `<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsomething="something"> $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {`. This seems to be related to CloudFlare's Rocket Loader service, but I don't see why it would be used for an inline script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the top of the page under the header.

I thought it was best to put jquery at the bottom?

Did it fail because I was trying to run that script before it loaded jquery?

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. You can't call jQuery functions before you defined them.

Comment: You can put jQuery at the bottom, but then you also have to put the scripts that use it at the bottom.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I see that now! I removed the script from my html file and added it to a .js file I have for other things and made sure that .js file was after the main jquery file. It worked perfectly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e)
```

To

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event)
```

Because you use

```
event.preventDefault();
```